How to use Jekyll github-pages with Ruby 3
I use Jekyll and Github Pages.  However, when I run with Ruby 3, I experience errors when trying to serve the site locally.  Specifically:
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
[...]
jekyll 3.10.0 | Error:  tried to create Proc object without a block
[...]

I read that the github-pages gem has issues with Ruby 3.  Is there any way to make it work with Ruby 3?

There appears to be a simple solution:
$ bundle add webrick
$ rm Gemfile.lock
$ bundle install

Unfortunately, the limitation to Ruby 2.7.x and the solution for Ruby 3 doesn't appear to be documented in the github-pages gem's documentation.
Credits: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/752#issuecomment-801924628, https://github.com/imagej/imagej.github.io/pull/133, https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/752#issuecomment-1401425888, https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/752#issuecomment-764758292
